# Addressing characters by [LastName-FirstName-LastName]

Tags: first-appearance, trope

There is a trope in American visual media (movies, television) in which a main character meets aliens or indigenous peoples unfamiliar with the name conventions of the character's culture.

Very commonly, the main character will introduce themselves as "John Doe" and the supporting characters will subsequently always refer to them by their first *and* last names as a compound word: "JohnDoe".

This gag became attenuated in the "Bond, James Bond" tradition, where the main character uses that structure to introduce themselves, and is subsequently always referred to as "DoeJohnDoe".

- What is the first appearance of either form of this gag?

Comment: Not confident enough to put this as an answer but its a joke in the books, radio-show, tv show and possibly movie of The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.  Arthur Dent introduces himself like that and is henceforth referred to as Dentarthurdent by one character.  So that would have first appeared in 1981 in TV form.

Comment: @iandotkelly nice instance, but it's definitely much older than Hitchhikers!

Comment: Why definitely? Are you aware of older instances? You might want to add those to your post.

Comment: @Joachim Honestly, I can't provide examples offhand, but people know what I'm talking about.  That said, three years with no answer... possibly time to kill this question?